# Hamachi replacement VPN server

Tags: vpn, openvpn, hamachi

This is my current situation:

I am running a "server" in my room at my university (I use it as a remote machine to do programming in a linux environment). It is behind the University network, so I obviously can't do any sort of port forwarding. I have Hamachi network which my laptop and server are both connected to that I can use to communicate to my server with. I occasionally will host some servers (like a small web server for one of my classes or a Jupyter Notebook), so I need some sort of VPN in order to be able to connect to my server. I recently setup an AWS EC2 instance so that it relays an SSH connection to the server, however I can't connected to servers like I listed above through this connect.

My issue with Hamachi is that I would get speeds of around 50-60 kpbs, which is annoyingly slow at times (especially for Jupyter Notebooks as I have found).

I want to convert my EC2 instance into a simple VPN that works as closely to Hamachi as possible (with a virtual network adapter if possible). I've been doing research for about an hour now and my head is just spinning at all the different possibilities.

I've been looking at OpenVPN, but all of the setup guides I can find are to make a home vpn server to secure internet connections (which feels like way more than I need). How should I setup OpenVPN in order to emulate as closely as possible, how Hamachi works (Hopefully with better connection speeds)?

Comment: I'm afraid that asking for product recommendations is off topic here.

Comment: I have modified the question in order to (hopefully) be 'on topic'